# R: Is there a way to index an array without knowing the number of its dimensions?

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I would like to experiment on random samples from various distributions. Specifically, for a specified family of distributions (e.g. Normal), I want to apply functions on random samples generated from different parameter values and save the result in an array of dimensions (No. functions) x (No. first prm values) x ... x (No. last prm values).

The following reproducible example creates a three dimensional array for the Normal distribution, where the dimensions correspond to the function applied, the value of the first parameter (mean) and the value of the second parameter (sd).

```
distr = "norm"
n     = 10
prm   = list(mean = c(1, 1.5), sd = c(1, 0.5))
fun   = c("sum", "mean", "prod")
dn    = c(list(fun = fun), prm)
y     = array(0, dim = lengths(dn), dimnames = dn)

for (i in prm$mean) {
  for (j in prm$sd) {
    z = do.call(get(paste0("r", distr)), list(n = n, mean = i, sd = j))
    for (f in fun) {
      y[f, as.character(i), as.character(j)] = do.call(f, list(z))
    }
  }
}
y
```

I would like to generalize the above example so that it works for other distributions, with variable number of parameters (e.g. one or three parameters). My question is the following:
Is there a way to subset an array with respect to all parameters, without a priori knowing their number? I know this could be achieved with the apply family, but is it possible in a for loop? The following (not working) example shows what I am trying to do.

```
prm.grid = expand.grid(prm)
for (i in 1:nrow(prm.grid)) {
  z = do.call(get(paste0("r", distr)), c(list(n = n), prm.grid[i,]))
  for (f in fun) {
    y[f, <all parameters> ] = do.call(f, list(z))
  }
}
y
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `[` operator is actually a function, so you can use `do.call` to call it with a dynamically determined number of parameters.  For example:

```
arr <- array(1:30, c(2,3,5))
```

Entry `arr[1,2,3]` is 15; you can get that this way:

```
do.call(`[`, c(list(arr), as.list(1:3)))
```

**Edited to add:** In the comment, you point out something I missed in the original question:  you want to assign into `arr[1,2,3]`, you don't just want to extract values.  As you said there, you need to call `[<-` instead.  Your example was

```
arr <- do.call("[<-", c(list(arr), as.list(1:3), 7))
```

You worried that this would duplicate `arr` each time.  You can test that using `tracemem()`.

You have to be careful doing this:  you'll get different results in RStudio (which makes more copies) than in plain R.  (I think RStudio makes copies when it is producing the Environment pane.)

Here's what I see when I run in R.app on a Mac:

```
> arr <- array(1:30, c(2,3,5))
> tracemem(arr)
[1] "<0x7f9310f65b68>"
> arr <- do.call("[<-", c(list(arr), as.list(1:3), 8))
tracemem[0x7f9310f65b68 -> 0x7f9310f66038]: do.call 
tracemem[0x7f9310f66038 -> 0x7f933719eaf0]: do.call 
> arr <- do.call("[<-", c(list(arr), as.list(1:3), 9))
tracemem[0x7f933719eaf0 -> 0x7f932fcf0130]: do.call 
> arr[1,2,3] <- 6
> arr[1,2,3] <- 7
```

So you are right:  the simple version without `do.call` appears to make changes in place, while `do.call` makes one or two copies.

If that's important to you, a hackish way to do it would be to prepare expressions and evaluate them.  For example:

```
template <- quote(arr[] <- 10)
indices <- 1:3
expr <- template
for (i in seq_along(indices))
 expr[[c(2,2+i)]] <- indices[i] 
eval(expr)
```

Personally, I wouldn't recommend this approach; it seems way too complicated to me.  You might think it's simpler to make an expression as text and parse it; I'd recommend even more strongly against that.  Parsing text can be very error prone, and can even be a security risk if you don't have complete control over the `indices` array.

Comment: I want to pass those values in `arr`, so something like `do.call("[<-", c(list(arr), as.list(1:3), 7))` would do the job, but since I want to do this globally, it would have to be something like `arr = do.call("[<-", c(list(arr), as.list(1:3), 7))`. This however seems to be an inefficient solution that creates the whole array over and over again.

Comment: I've added another approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and updated response. Indeed, I want to avoid this solution, since in the real problem I am working on there are more dimensions and the array can reach up to a couple Gbs of memory.

Comment: You might want to think of a different way to organize your data.  For example, lists act like vectors of pointers, so changing an entry in an element of a list might reallocate that element and the vector of pointers, but typically won't reallocate any other elements.