# R: How to remove elements from last dimension of array, when number of dimensions not known a priori?

Tags: r, arrays, subset

I would like to remove some elements from the last dimension of an array – but a priori I don't know the number of dimensions of the array, which could be 2 or more.

Suppose the elements to remove are in the vector (values are unimportant)

```
toremove <- c(2,5,6)
```

If `A` is my array and I knew it was, say, 3-dimensional, then I could do

```
Anew <- A[, , -toremove, drop=F]
```

(where `drop` is included to preserve the dimensionality in case all elements are dropped but one), and similarly if `A` had some other dimension, simply using the appropriate number of commas `,`.

But what if I don't know the dimensions of `A`? I would like to find a solution that's short, fast, and preferably doesn't lead to many copies of `A` in intermediate steps.

(From what I see it doesn't really matter if the dimension of interest is the last or the first.)

What I've considered:

- Check `dim(A)` and from it calculate the *absolute* index of all elements to remove from `c(A)`; then re-adjust the dimensionality.
- Check `dim(A)` and proceed on a case-by-case basis for each possible dimensionality, with some `if` statements.
- Possibly use `do.call` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71470546/6090141) – but I haven't managed to use this idea: I don't know how to give the empty arguments `,...,` to `do.call`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to have empty arguments in a constructed call list via `alist`. If we do, for example:

```r
 alist(,)[1]
#> [[1]]
```

Then we have an empty list element, which we can pass to `rep` to have multiple empty arguments. This allows us to construct exactly the call we want via this function:

```r
call_to_remove_last <- function(A, ind) {
  
  args <- c(quote(`[`),
            substitute(A), 
            rep(alist(,)[1], length(dim(A)) - 1), 
            substitute(ind), 
            drop = FALSE)
  
  as.call(args)
}
```

Let's test this on a dummy 3d and 4d array:

```
arr_3d <- array(1:24, dim = c(2, 2, 6))
arr_4d <- array(1:120, dim = c(5, 2, 2, 6))
toremove <- c(2, 5, 6)

call_to_remove_last(arr_3d, toremove)
#> arr_3d[, , toremove, drop = FALSE]

call_to_remove_last(arr_4d, toremove)
#> arr_4d[, , , toremove, drop = FALSE]
```

The function we actually want just takes the extra step of evaluating this call:

````r
remove_last <- function(A, ind) {
  
  args <- c(quote(`[`),
            substitute(A), 
            rep(alist(,)[1], length(dim(A)) - 1), 
            substitute(ind), 
            drop = FALSE)
  
  eval(as.call(args))
}
``
When we test, we see that the final dimension has dropped by length 3, as expected:
```r
dim(remove_last(arr_3d, toremove))
#> [1] 2 2 3

dim(remove_last(arr_4d, toremove))
#> [1] 5 2 2 3
````

<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! And doubly so for explaining about `alist`, which I had never heard about. Please give me just a couple days to invite other answers, then I'm hayy to accept this as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that option 3 in my question can work if we use `TRUE` where commas are missing:

```
Anew <- do.call('[', c(list(A), rep(TRUE, length(dim(A))-1), list(-toremove), list(drop=FALSE))
```

I'm happy to hear about better solutions, though.